# How to check if combination of key,value pair exists in Map

Tags: scala, dictionary, scala-collections

I am trying to solve a problem where I want to check if pair of key value exist in Map
I have map like this :

```
val codemap = new Map[String, List[String]]
```

I want to make map with static values

```
val codeMap = Map(
  "Asset Banking" -> List("audio","doc"),
  "avalon" -> List("adaptive-module", "ebook-plus")
)
```

I have 2 variable which are dynamic:

```
val a: Option[String] = Option("Asset Banking")
val b: Option[String] = Option("audio")
```

I want to check if combination of a& B is present :

The logic i can think of is

```
    if(codemap.key.contains (a))
    {
      if(codemap.values exist for above key)
         then do something 

     }else
     {
       do something
     }
```

Is this a good way to approach this?
This is steaming data `a`,`b` are fields coming from stream 
I want to populate a third field in table call it `c` based on values of `a`,`b`

`a`,`b` needs to be some combination that will be stored in map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
(for {
  k <- a
  v <- b
  l <- codeMap.get(k)
} yield {
  l.contains(v)
}).getOrElse(false)
```

which outputs `true` if combination is found, otherwise `false`.

Comment: i want if condition to be true if conbination exist in map. result is giving me the values . is result gonna be null if combination does not exists. @mario Galic

Comment: Add `l <- codeMap.get(k)` as the 3rd generator. Then you can `yield l.contains(v)` which should reduce the iterations through `codeMap`.

Answer (score 0):

`find` can operate on the `key` and `value` of each element in your Map returning an `Option` if the value exists in the map.

```
scala> codeMap.find({case (a,b) => a  == "Asset Banking" && b == List()})
res14: Option[(String, List[String])] = None

scala> codeMap.find({case (a,b) => a  == "Asset Banking" && b == List("audio", "doc")})
res15: Option[(String, List[String])] = Some((Asset Banking,List(audio, doc)))
```

Comment: will I be able to use codemap.find inside if statement. I want if to be true if the combination exists.

Comment: The `if` statement expects a boolean value so to use it you'll have to call `isDefined` on the `Option` values returned.

Comment: It would be better to use `exists`.